# JFace add a Text box near a RadioGroupFieldEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I try to add some preferences in the Eclipse menu and for that I create in JFace a RadioGroupFieldEditor section and near the last radio of the RadioGroupField, I want to have a text area, like in the picture below:
[image]

However I am not able to do this. I create a GridLayout with two columns, in one column I want the RadioGroupFieldEditor , in the other I want the text field. The text field is put below the RadioGroupField, not in the second column like I expect.

here is the code:

```
    protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    Composite fieldEditorParent = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 1;
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 0;
    fieldEditorParent.setLayout(layout);
    fieldEditorParent.setFont(parent.getFont());

    createAGroup(fieldEditorParent);

    return fieldEditorParent;
  }

  private void createAGroup(Composite parent) {
    Group group = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
    group.setText("Group");
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 1;
    group.setLayout(layout);

    GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    group.setLayoutData(data);

    GridLayout subLayout = new GridLayout();
    subLayout.numColumns = 3;

    Composite expertUserComposite1 = new Composite(group, SWT.NONE);
    expertUserComposite1.setLayout(subLayout);
    new Button(expertUserComposite1, SWT.RADIO | SWT.LEFT);
    new Label(expertUserComposite1, SWT.BEGINNING).setText("aaa");
    new Text(expertUserComposite1, SWT.BORDER);

    Composite expertUserComposite2 = new Composite(group, SWT.NONE);
    expertUserComposite2.setLayout(subLayout);
    new Button(expertUserComposite2, SWT.RADIO | SWT.LEFT);
    new Label(expertUserComposite2, SWT.BEGINNING).setText("bbb");

    Composite expertUserComposite3 = new Composite(group, SWT.NONE);
    expertUserComposite3.setLayout(subLayout);

    new RadioGroupFieldEditor(IExportCSVPreferences.DELIMITER_NAME_CURRENT,
        "RadioGroup", 1,
        new String[][] { { "line1", "line1" }, { "line2", "line2" }, { "line3", "line3" } },
        expertUserComposite3);
    new Text(expertUserComposite3, SWT.BORDER);

    Composite expertUserComposite4 = new Composite(group, SWT.NONE);
    expertUserComposite4.setLayout(subLayout);

    new RadioGroupFieldEditor(IExportCSVPreferences.DELIMITER_NAME_CURRENT, "RadioGroup", 1,
        new String[][] { { "line1", "line1" }, { "line2", "line2" }, { "line3", "line3" } }, expertUserComposite4,
        true);
    new Text(expertUserComposite4, SWT.BORDER);
  }
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: `RadioGroupFieldEditor` does not support this.

Comment: Why does expertUserCompositeGroup3 have 3 columns and where is the Griddata for that panel?